# In List view when List Item clicked It shoud be flash different color background while a second(only clicked Item), how can I do this?

Tags: android

My List View

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:focusable="true" android:background="@drawable/newshape_list"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff" android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:footerDividersEnabled = "false" android:headerDividersEnabled = "false"
    android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:paddingRight="1dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip" android:divider="#A9ABAD"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"/>
```

in drawable my list_selector.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

</selector>
```

in Value folder I have made color.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <drawable name="focused">#ff5500</drawable>
  <drawable name="selected">#FF00FF</drawable>
</resources>
```

and in java file this code

```
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv1.setSelector( R.drawable.list_selector);
```